# How to add comments or notes with attachments on Trello

Tags: trello

I want to couple a comment and an attachment, but it seems that attachments exist separately from comments. I want to make a feature request, but before I do, I'd like to make sure it's not possible.

I use Trello in my research, almost as a lab notebook. I have comments about my progress on a task, and frequently I also include plots as image attachments. I'd like to add a comment specific to the image, and usually I have to do this subsequently as a separate comment: "The plot attached below shows ...".

**Is there a way to add a comment to an attachment?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't currently a way to add an attachment to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

### Comment Referenced Attachments Markdown-powered Workaround

Per @bobby-grace, not currently supported.

I work around this with card attachments + Markdown.

For example, I upload an `image.jpg` to my card which I'd like to reference in a comment:

1. Upload `image.jpg` to Trello card.
2. Right click on the attachment's associated **Download** link > copy link address.
   *This is how you copy a link address in Google Chrome. IE, Safari, FireFox, etc share this functionality, but might call it something else.*
3. Make use of the GitHub-flavored markdown "linking" syntax in your comment. Paste that link between the `[` square brackets `]` like so:

   > here's that `[image.jpg](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/589f2f4cbcfb178dd45a1c2a/58a8573c44ecd49c277cade6/f4c6d9f67dd479d5821a5f2e3784e7dd/upload_2_26_2017_at_2_15_05_PM.png)`
4. Attach/Reference stuff in comments
   [image]